# "val++" vs "val = val + 1" What is exact difference?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, short

I created a basic console application to make such a test.

```
        short val = 32767;

        val++;

        Console.WriteLine(val);
```

This gives me **-32768** as an expected result

```
        short val = 32767;

        val = val +1;

        Console.WriteLine(val);
```

But this gives me this error

**Error 1   **Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

I am curious about what causes this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result of a `short + short` operation is defined as an `int`. In the first case, the compiler is going ahead and applying a `(short)` cast on the result of the increment, but it is not in the second.

```
short myShort = 1;
int resultA = myShort + myShort; // addition returns an integer
short resultB = myShort++; // returns a short, why? 

// resultB is essentially doing this
short resultB = (short)(myShort + 1);
```

In addition to the link provided by Joel in the comments, you can also refer to section 7.3.6.2 of the [C# 4.0 language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) that lays out the rules for binary numeric promotions (covering expressions of the form `a = b + c;`) and also 7.6.9 that covers pre- and postfix operators.

Comment: +1: As an addendum, here is the MSDN resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Adding two `short`s will return an `int`.

The `+=` and `++` operators [behave differently](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx) and work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The result of addition of two shorts, or a short and an int, as in your case, is always of type int, which needs to get converted back to short in order to be assigned to val.

The reason why this is so is that the sum of two shorts, or a short and an int may not fit into short, so is always int. Consider this;

```
short x = 30000;
short y = 30000;

int z = x+y; // would you really want to get a number other than 60000 here?  
short s = (short)(x+y); //if you want modulo 2^16
```

Answer (score 0):

The `1` in your line:

```
val = val +1;
```

is an `int` implicitly, so the result of `val + 1` is an `int`. You're trying to assign that value a short, and that can't be done implicitly because you'd risk losing some precision.

Answer (score 0):

Using `val + 1` makes it think it's an integer.

Using:

```
    short val = 32767;

    val = (short) (val + 1);

    Console.WriteLine(val);
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation of numbers defaults to int (Int32).

In your case here, you're trying to add an short(Int16) to an int(Int32) type. This correctly throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
val = val +1;
```

Here, `1` is of type `int` so is `val + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `val++`, you just increment the value stored in the variable.

When you run `val=val+1`, `1` is an `int` by default so the compiler considers both values to be `ints` and returns an `int` with the value `val+1`. Then it fails to put it back into `val` because an `int` is to large to store in a short.